# BizTalk and SalesForce integration: the query or retrieve function returns unknown type

Tags: xml, salesforce, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I'm integration a legacy on premise BizTalk Server with SFDC (Salesforce CRM on Demand). I'm using BizTalk 2009 with WCF custom ports. I have imported the enterprise WSDL and successfully used it to create an accounts in SFDC. The problem occurs when I try to use the retrieve (or query) function to get user details, everything is working nicely except when I try to "use" the response message.

Request:

```
<ns0:retrieve xmlns:ns1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns0="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <ns0:fieldList>Name, Email</ns0:fieldList>
    <ns0:sObjectType>User</ns0:sObjectType>
    <ns0:ids>005900000023xmcAAA</ns0:ids>
</ns0:retrieve>
```

Receive pipeline is the standard XMLReceive.

Response message:

```
<retrieveResponse xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <result xsi:type="sf:User" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <sf:Id xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">005900000023xmcAAA</sf:Id>
        <sf:Email xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">jredwood@charteredaccountants.com.au</sf:Email>
        <sf:Name xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">Julian Redwood</sf:Name>
    </result>
</retrieveResponse>
```

Error Details:"Unable to read the stream produced by the pipeline. 
 Details: The value 'sf:User' is invalid according to its schema type '[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:QName](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema%3aQName)' - 'sf' is an undeclared namespace. ".

Comment: Can you post the schema for the response?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that response is rather messed up.

It declares the a default name space at the root xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
It doesn't declare the sf namespace prefix at the root e.g. (xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com").
And then for user has it as xsi:type="sf:User" where it then doesn't have the sf prefix defined for the result node.

Either it needs to declare it either in the root or at the result node level.

Option 1) If you the ESB Toolkit you could try and use the ESB Add Namespace pipeline component and add the NamspacePrefix = sf and NamspaceBase = urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com

Option 2) Raise it as in issue with Salesforce as that is not valid.

Or both.

Comment: Thanks -  this confirmed my suspicion that the response is not "well formed" - I thought maybe I wasn't using it correctly. 

I have tried using the ESB add namespace, but had another issue with it.  I'm using a common send/rcv port for the enterprise wsdl and did not want to use a specific pipeline component, but maybe I'll need to . . .

I'll log a call with SF. I'm surprised I can't get any hits from google for this issue.

J